# Google Drive API Java IntelliJ Setup

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to write a simple program that renames video files and uploads them directly to Google Drive using Google Drive API. I have already in the Main class written code to rename my files. My next step is I'd like to upload them to the drive.

My trouble is in integrating the Google Drive API to my existing code. I have followed the quick setup guide here : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java , I have the gradle build and credentials and all, but I have trouble understanding how my classes will interact. My imports have errors, and my project directory looks atrocious. I'm hoping someone can take a look on how this came to be and how can I resolve it.

[image: My Project Directory]

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the project of the plugin DriveBackupV2 to see how other people did this
(https://github.com/MaxMaeder/DriveBackupV2)
You can do that too so you have the libraries needed:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn7My.png)

When you added these you have to paste

```
    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
                        <version>v2-rev393-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

into your pom.xml (yes the indents are wrong)
and then all the other needed libraries will be added automatically